# Show that the set of functions $\{ e^{2x}, x^2,x\}$ is linearly independent in vector space of continuous functions defined in R

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the set of functions $\{ e^{2x}, x^2,x\}$ is linearly independent in vector space of continuous functions defined in $\mathbb{R}$

Last Wednesday my teacher asked this question.
From where should I start solving?

Comment: exponentials aren't polynomials, and $x^2$ can't be written in terms of $x$

Comment: "where should i start solving?" ----> $ae^{2x}+bx^2+cx=0$, where else... ?

Comment: You can take a linear combination and use some values of $x$, then form an equation system such that all the scalars of the linear combination are zero

Comment: My guess is that this problem intends for you to compute the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)

Comment: The teacher might also want the OP to use the Wronskian.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your instructor intends for you to compute the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian). When the determinant of the Wronskian is non-zero, the functions are linearly independent.

$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
  e^{2x} & x^2 & x \\
  2e^{2x} & 2x & 1 \\
  4e^{2x} & 2  &  0
\end{vmatrix} &= 
x\begin{vmatrix}
  2e^{2x} & 2x \\
  4e^{2x} & 2
\end{vmatrix} -
\begin{vmatrix}
  e^{2x} & x^2 \\
  4e^{2x} & 2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=
xe^{2x}(4 - 8x) - e^{2x}(2 - 4x^2)\\
&= e^{2x}(-4x^2 + 4x - 2)
\end{align*}
$$ which is not the zero function—which you can check by evaluating at $x=1$. Thus the functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the equation $ae^{2x}+bx^{2}+cx=0$ by $e^{2x}$ and let $x \to \infty$. Since $\frac {x^{n}} {e^{2x}} \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty$ for any $n$ we get $a=0$. Now you are left with $bx^{2}+cx=0$ from which it is easy to see that $b=c=0$.

Comment: @YiFan Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Why not just set $x=0$ to get $a=0$ ? The first step you proposed seems a complication.

Comment: @zwim You are right. I missed that simple point.